# app_offline asp.net 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

Why app_offline.htm is created automatically? and my project do not work ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking about..... how does your project "not work" ??

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio creates asp_offline.htm when you load or close a project to protect from compile and errors at the time of loading.

If in that time you have a crash or big delay you see this.